# Implementing paging in Sitecore content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, sitecore

I have a section on my website where I plan to add a lot of text-based content, and rather than display this all at once it would be nice if I could add paging on just these pages. If possible, I would like to put all of my content within one content item and have the paging work automatically, building a URL along the lines of http://example.org/articles/title?page=2 or similar.

I've stumbled across an article that mentions paging with Sitecore items and this seems rather close to what I require, although mine requires pagination on a single content item, rather than multiple items. Can someone help me adapt [this article](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/create-a-google-style-paging-component-in-c/) towards my needs (if it's on the right track of where I should be looking)?

Is it possible to do this with a Sitecore content item?

http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/create-a-google-style-paging-component-in-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd either want to create your own `WebControl` and define a custom `Render()` method that reads the query string to write out the correct information, or you could even do it all in a Sublayout (a user control ASCX file). I've done this before by adding in a custom tag in the Rich text editor via Sitecore (I think I used `<hr class="page-break" />`) then in my ASCX I'd look for that HTML tag and split the content into chunks from that. I think my solution also used jQuery for some of it but you could probably do it with C# too.

**Edit:**

You'd want to split the tasks up and have the "paged" content as well as a list of pages (like the article you referenced) so you can easily generate the page buttons. Both of these could be done in two separate repeaters.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the text from a single field into the different pages using approach described here: [Split html string to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526150/split-html-string-to-page). All you need to do after that - read the query string and display appropriate block.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have an Item in Sitecore that has x number of text fields and you only want a subset of those displayed depending on input in the querystring ?

In it's simplest form you want a sublayout that handles that.

Basically I'd imagine you having fields called Text1, Text2, text3 etc.

This .ascx could then retrieve the data for fields the fields you'd want using the  control and adding them.

Then you could use the code from the article to generate the paging links.

This should be simple enough, but I'd say it would be a better idea to have an item in sitecore and use it's children as the data you want viewed and paged.

It's nicer because if you start out with 5 "page" fields and suddenly want 10, your item will keep on growing, where children can be added without bloating the parent page. Plus the user could then order the children how he sees fit.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: The issue with this is that there is no set amount of pages. Some bits of content will be around 5-10 pages, whereas some may be close to 50 pages. The user also wants to be able to paste in the entire document into a single field in a single content item and have pagination work. This is where I'm somewhat stuck with how to implement pagination on a single chunk of text. I agree that it would make more sense to use children for each page and create a simple paging user-control.

Comment: Hm... if they only want to have a single field, you'll have to setup some rules, otherwise it'll get messy.

Something like it shows 5 <p>-tags per page. It's gonna be very hard to define it by the size (as things like <ul> & <br /> will mess up how long a <p> would be). But while you could do some splitting of the text based on some tags, it's not gonna be the easiest solution, esp. if the data the users want to paste some from different sources.